# Pass a List of Objects from a support.v4 FragmentActivity to a fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-2.2-froyo, android-support-library

I am working in an android application and I want to pass a List of Objects from my fragment activity to Fragment. And I am using android support library to implement fragments since minSdkVersion is 8.

I have already passed these List of Objects from one activity to another activity by implementing my model classes with Parcelable.

So please suggest me a good solution to pass my List of objects from my fragment activity to Fragment. .